# Why was using rockets to propel a winged vehicle not proposed in the 19th century?

Tags: steam-engines

My understanding that among the key technologies that allowed manned flight was a powerful enough engine that was also lightweight. Steam was attempted but the gasoline engine turned out to be key.

Two other technologies besides steam and gasoline occur to me: rockets and compressed air, both of which were well understood in the 19th century.

Comment: See [Wikipedia's Rocket, history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket#History):"*William Leitch first proposed the concept of using rockets to enable human spaceflight in 1861. Konstantin Tsiolkovsky later (in 1903) also conceived this idea, and extensively developed a body of theory that has provided the foundation for subsequent spaceflight development.*"

Comment: @Conifold winged vehicles

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [Rocket-powered aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-powered_aircraft) too, and also with a history section.

Comment: @conifold: Nothing about wings though.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Click on the links and look at the pictures.

Comment: @conifold: No need - I've looked through it once. There's a separate article on Wikipedia on the history of rockets which mentions Fontaines bird like rocket.